# How to get json Object value inside array in on java

Tags: java

Here Is my json

```
{
  "network-status": {
    "interfaces": [
      "eth0",
      {
        "status": {
          "RX": {
            "packets": "766292",
            "errors": "0",
            "dropped": "68",
            "overruns": "0",
            "frame": "0",
            "bytes": "739960761"
          },
          "TX": {
            "packets": "356928",
            "errors": "0",
            "dropped": "0",
            "overruns": "0",
            "carrier": "0",
            "bytes": "54835108"
          }
        }
      },
      "lo",
      {
        "status": {
          "RX": {
            "packets": "967",
            "errors": "0",
            "dropped": "0",
            "overruns": "0",
            "frame": "0",
            "bytes": "185357"
          },
          "TX": {
            "packets": "967",
            "errors": "0",
            "dropped": "0",
            "overruns": "0",
            "carrier": "0",
            "bytes": "185357"
          }
        }
      },
      "mlan0",
      {
        "status": {
          "RX": {
            "packets": "272573",
            "errors": "272573",
            "dropped": "0",
            "overruns": "7229",
            "frame": "0",
            "bytes": "275867466"
          },
          "TX": {
            "packets": "542",
            "errors": "0",
            "dropped": "0",
            "overruns": "0",
            "carrier": "0",
            "bytes": "30056"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "NumberOfProcess": "261",
  "CPU Usage": "13.5473%",
  "Disk Usage": "23%",
  "Up Time": "2 hours, 7 minutes"
}
```

Here is my Java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                "/jsonfile.log"));


        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONObject netWorkStatus = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("network-status");
        JSONArray interfaces = (JSONArray)netWorkStatus.get("interfaces");           
        String firstValue = (String) interfaces.get(0);


        for (int i = 0; i < firstValue.length(); ++i) {
            String x = (String) firstValue.get(0).getJSONObject("RX");              
        }                       

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

so here, how can I get `bytes` value of object `TX` inside `lo`.

Answer (score 1):

JSONobjects have a method called `getJSONArray`

```
JSONArray interfaces = netWorkStatus.getJSONArray("interfaces");
```

to get TX inside lo

```
interfaces.get(0).JSONObject("lo").JSONObject("TX");
```